# Add custom cell to only one case of Segmented Controller

Tags: swift, uitableview, xcode7, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a question about adding an additional custom cell to only one case for a Segmented Controller. I want to add a "Add Item" action cell to a tableview only on case 3 for the segmented controller. Does anyone know how to implement this or where I can find a good resource (besides Apple documentation) to see how to do this. Thanks!

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var mySegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

let globalList: [String] = ["Global Item 1","Global Item 2", "Global Item 3"]
let friendsList: [String] = ["Friend 1", "Friend 2", "Friend 3"]
let meList: [String] = ["Milan, Italy", "Rome, Italy", "Napoli, Italy", "Paris, France"]

let addButton: [String] = ["+ Add item"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}





 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{


    var returnValue = 0

    switch(mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {

    case 0:
        returnValue = globalList.count
        break

    case 1:
        returnValue = friendsList.count
        break

    case 2:

        // *** I want to add a Cell here with an "Add Item" IBAction ---------------------

        returnValue = meList.count
        break

    default:
        break

    }

    return returnValue

}



@available(iOS 2.0, *)
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    switch(mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)

    {
    case 0:
        myCell.textLabel!.text = globalList[indexPath.row]
        break

    case 1:
        myCell.textLabel!.text = friendsList[indexPath.row]
        break

    case 2:
```

// *** I want to add a Cell here with a "Add Item" IBAction ---------------------

```
        myCell.textLabel?.text = meList[indexPath.row]
        break

    default:
        break

    }

    return myCell

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add new cell in your 3rd segment case do the following changes in your code.

**In your switch case statement,**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
  case 2:
    returnValue = meList.count +1

    break
}
```

**Now in your cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
   let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

   switch(mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
   {
       case 2:
       if(indexPath.row == meList.count) {
         myCell.textLabel?.text = "Add Item"  
         // add new row here 
         /* OR add new button here as cell's subview  */
           // set frame of your button
           // set target and selector method of button
           [cell addSubView: addButton]
       }
       else {
          myCell.textLabel?.text = meList[indexPath.row]
       } 

       break
   }
```

**In your didSelectRowAtIndexPath if you didn't use button approach.**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

 switch(mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
 {
   case 2:
   if(indexPath.row == meList.count) {
     // do your work here, this is the click event of your "Add Item" cell
   }

 }
}
```

Comment: Another quick question...how would I make the "Add Item" cell always default to the top of the tableview? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You can do it by 2 ways: You can take a view containing your button and add that view as a Table's headerView. OR you can add new row instead that button as always on first indexPath.